# Send templates in mailchimp with my django application

Tags: python, django, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have a mailchimp account with templates in it. I am able to integrate this to my django application and I am able to read the templates data in JSON format. Now I want to email these templates within my django application but I did not find any documentation on how to get the html form of the template in mailchimp and send it to individual emails. Below is the code I used to get the templates information

```
client = MailChimp(mc_api='API_Key', mc_user='user')
    clients = client.templates.all(get_all=False)
    for template in clients["templates"]:
        print(template["name"])
```

Comment: Are you trying to send the emails through django's email capabilities, or are you trying to send emails via the mailchimp api?

Comment: @2ps if I could send it through mailchimp with the template that will be great. But if I could some how use the JSON data to render it as a html template and use that in Django’s send_email that word too.

Comment: Am facing a similar issue at the moment. Have you found the solution to connect to mailchimp's API and `/message/send` endpoint and provide an HTML template in your request?